# Web API / WCF how keep object alive

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have an engine (ABBYY FlexiCapture Engine), and I want to use it with REST service ( WebAPI or WCF).
Engine start initialization takes 30 seconds. It is too long for every request. I want engine to be loaded with service start and stay in "warmup" state.
How can I do it with WebAPI or WCF? (what is the best approach keep thread with engine alive).
PS: sorry for my bad English.

-- from ABBYY Example library

```
private void ProcessImages()
        {
            trace("Loading FlexiCapture Engine...");
            IEngine engine = LoadEngine();
            try
            {
                string samplesFolder = FceConfig.GetSamplesFolder();

                trace("Creating and configuring the FlexiCapture Processor...");
                IFlexiCaptureProcessor processor = engine.CreateFlexiCaptureProcessor();
                processor.AddDocumentDefinitionFile(samplesFolder + "\\SampleProject\\Templates\\Invoice_eng.fcdot");
                // ....

                trace("Adding images to process...");
                processor.AddImageFile(samplesFolder + "\\SampleImages\\Invoices_1.tif");
                // ....

                trace("Recognizing the images and exporting the results...");

                while (true)
                {
                    // Recognize next document
                    IDocument document = processor.RecognizeNextDocument();
                    // processing recognized document...
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                UnloadEngine(ref engine);
            }
        }

        private IEngine LoadEngine()
        {
            // FlexiCapture Engine can be loaded in three diffrent ways:
            // 1) Directly, as in this sample
            // 2) As an inproc server (using COM infrastructure)
            // 3) As an out-of-proc server in a worker process (using COM infrastructure)

            IEngine engine;
            int hResult = InitializeEngine(FceConfig.GetDeveloperSN(), null, null, out engine);
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hResult);
            return engine;
        }
```

I want create engine. After that, I will create and configure several FlexiCapture Processors. (it takes long time, i want to do it on service startup)
Than, when user add images - i will use one of the Processors to recognize them.

on startup:
Create engine -> Create several Processors (+configure them);
on method invoke:
Take one of free processors -> recognize user images.

Comment: Can you post the code which is managing the lifetime of the engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, you need to implement static singleton instance of your Engine and use context

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public static class EngineContainer
{
    private static Engine _engine { get; set; }
    public static Engine GetEngine 
    {
        get { if (_engine == null) Init(); return _engine; }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this will probably work, it is not recommended to use singleton service instances unless absolutely necessary as they do not scale

Comment: @Tom Redfern: High initialization cost is a perfectly valid reason for implementing SingleInstance mode. Actually, it may very well be the ONLY valid reason for doing so :)

Comment: @JohannBlais I agree with you that high initialization cost is a valid reason to use a singleton. What I am saying is that you better be sure that this is the case. The OP's problem as currently described does not sound like one of unavoidable warm-up cost but rather one of lifetime management, i.e. creation of a new instance of an external resource stack for each service request.

Comment: What will be better in this case - use WCF + REST or WebAPI?

Comment: WCF + REST couse you have more control of settings

Answer (score -2):

If your engine don't have any user interface(UI) then you can make use of Windows Services with WCF (self host). Let Windows services to take care of your engine (ie. live object) and handle to user request via WCF services

Comment: Service must be hosted on IIS. Yes, engine don't have any user interface.

Comment: why you are prefer to host in IIS only?

Comment: This will not address the OP's problem.